# Reading multiple lines in c++ if the file is unknown

Tags: c++

I got in a file bac.txt 2 different lines and I got to read both of them,what can I do in this situation?

Comment: well I am not that skilled in these types of problems,I know how to read in stuff from a file,but still didn't learn how to read in different lines...

Answer (score 1):

You should use standard function `std::getline` with argument of type `std::string` and after that use `std::istringstream` to parse each line.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

//...

std::string line;

while ( std::getline( YourFile, line )
{
   std::istringstream is( line );
   // using `operator >>` to read items in the line
}
```